# Chain Rule of Partial Derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $f$ is a differentiable function defined $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f(2,1) = 3$ and $\nabla f(2,1) = (4,3)$, find $\nabla G(1,1)$ with $G(x,y) := x^2yf(x^2 +y^2, xy)$.

I wrote the $G_x$ as $2xyf(x^2 +y^2, xy) + x^2yf'(x^2 + y^2, xy)f_x(x^2 + y^2, xy)$ but I don't know what the value of $f'(x^2 + y^2, xy)$ is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To answer the value of $f'$, first you have to answer what is $f'$ in a multivariable sense?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you computed $\partial_x f(x^2 + y^2, xy)$ incorrectly. Define $h:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by $h(x,y) = (x^2 + y^2, xy)$ and use the chain rule on $f(h(x,y))$ to get the correct formula, namely $2xf_x(x^2 + y^2,xy) + yf_y(x^2 + y^2, xy)$. Remember, it's the sum of the partials in each slot times the derivative of function you see in that slot.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wondering about the inner mechanisms of the chain rule for partial derivatives, you can read about it on [Paul's Online Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChainRule.aspx), specifically under 'Case 2'. If you think of $\nabla f(x,y)$ as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\boldsymbol{i} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\boldsymbol{j}$, you know that at point $(2,1)$ $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 4$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 3$.

Next you can set $u(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ and $v(x,y) = xy$ and use the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$, $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$, and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ to create a new expression...

$\nabla f(u,v) = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x})\boldsymbol{i} + (\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y})\boldsymbol{j}$

From the logic of the first paragraph, you know what the values of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$ are at the point $(2,1)$. The expressions in the parentheses transform that $f(u,v)$ result in terms of the $x$ and $y$ used in $G(x,y)$.

Comment: I don't think I am convinced by your conclusion about the values of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$. $(2,1)$ is the point where the function and gradient are being evaluated, thus $x=2$, $y=1$

Comment: Thanks, it was a careless mistake. Edited the original to reflect my original intention.

Comment: Sorry, I had poorly grouped the partials into directional sums in my original definition of $\nabla f(u,v)$, fixed that too. The form I've written checks with [WolframAlpha's answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=del%28x^2*y*f%28x^2%2By^2%2Cxy%29%29) for the form of the gradient as well. Just wanted to double-check my work.

Comment: **For clarity:** By definition $\nabla f(u,v) = \langle f_u(u,v), f_v(u,v)\rangle$ , so therefore we have been given that $f_u(2,1)=4$ and $f_v(2,1)=3$.  
Now let $w=xy^2, u=x^2+y^2, v=xy$, so $G(x,y)= w~f(u,v)$.

Then apply the product and chain rule: $$\begin{align}G_x(x,y) &= {[w~f(u,v)]}'_x\\&= w_x~f(u,v)+w~{[f(u,v)]}'_x\\&= w_x~f(u,v)+w~\big(u_x~f_u(u,v)+v_x~f_v(u,v)\big)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Denote
$$g(x,y)=x^{2}y$$
Then by product rule
$$\nabla G=f\nabla g+g\nabla f$$
$$\nabla g=2xy\boldsymbol{i}+x^{2}\boldsymbol{j}$$
Now write
$$\begin{cases}
x^{2}+y^{2} & =2\\
xy & =1
\end{cases}$$
Multiply the second equation by 2, add and subtract from the first one obtaining respectively
$$\left(x+y\right)^{2}=4$$
$$\left(x-y\right)^{2}=0$$
Hence
$$x=y=\pm1$$
Finally
$$\nabla G\left(1,1\right)=3\left(2\boldsymbol{i}+1\boldsymbol{j}\right)+4\boldsymbol{i}+3\boldsymbol{j}=10\boldsymbol{i}+6\boldsymbol{j}$$